# Web Crawler in Go

Tags: beginner, web-scraping, go

I'm a beginner in Go, and just finished the Golang tour. This crawler is not the same as the one in the exercises in the tour but something I wrote myself. I am looking for suggestions for making it better in terms of idiomatic Go.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
    "net/http"
    "log"
    "regexp"
    "io/ioutil"
)

type Crawler struct {
    urls map[string]bool
    mux sync.Mutex
    umatch *regexp.Regexp
}

func (c Crawler) parse(body string) (urls []string) {
   return c.umatch.FindAllString(body, -1)
}

func (c Crawler) fetch(url string) (urls []string) {
    res, err := http.Get(url)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error in fetching %s: %s", url, err)
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer res.Body.Close()
    body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(res.Body)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    urls = c.parse(string(body))
    return
}

func (c Crawler) Crawl(url string, depth int) {
    if depth <= 0 {
        return
    }

    c.mux.Lock()
    if c.urls[url] { //Already exists
        c.mux.Unlock()
        return
    }
    c.urls[url] = true
    c.mux.Unlock()

    log.Println("Fetching %s", url)
    fetched := c.fetch(url)
    for _, u := range fetched {
        go c.Crawl(u, depth - 1)
    }
    return
}

func main() {
    c := Crawler{urls : map[string]bool{}, umatch : regexp.MustCompile(`(http|ftp|https):\/\/([\w\-_]+(?:(?:\.[\w\-_]+)+))([\w\-\.,@?^=%&amp;:/~\+#]*[\w\-\@?^=%&amp;/~\+#])?`)}
    c.Crawl("http://www.yahoo.com", 3)
    for u, _ := range c.urls {
        fmt.Println(u)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I like regexes, so I can review the regex. (The only experience I have in Go is with regexes.)

It's pretty large, and you have numerous unnecessary characters. Look at it:

> ```
> (http|ftp|https):\/\/([\w\-_]+(?:(?:\.[\w\-_]+)+))([\w\-\.,@?^=%&amp;:/~\+#]*[\w\-\@?^=%&amp;/~\+#])?
> ```

1. Go does not use delimiters. `/` is not special and needs no escaping:

```
(http|ftp|https)://
```

2. `\w` already matches `_` (underscore), and `-` does not need to be escaped if it appears at the beginning or end of a character class:

```
([-\w]+(?:(?:\.[-\w]+)+))
```

3. There is no reason to escape `.` or `+` in a character class. Additionally, `amp` is all included as part of `\w`:

```
([-\w.,@?^=%&;:/~+#]*
```

It can be further shrunk if you use character ranges, but this is not very legible when it comes to special characters:

```
([\w+-/@?^=%&;:~#]*
```

4. I have no clue why you escaped the `@`. Of course it doesn't need escaping, since you didn't escape the other one!

```
[-\w@?^=%&;/~+#])?
```

#### To put it all together, the new regex would be:

```
(http|ftp|https)://([\w-]+(?:(?:\.[\w-]+)+))([-\w.,@?^=%&;:/~+#]*[-\w@?^=%&;/~+#])?
```

Answer (score 1):

I also wrote a crawler in go and have the following regex for sublinks only within the same domain.

```
    re := regexp.MustCompile("href=\"(.*?)\"")
    subre := regexp.MustCompile("\"/[\\w]+")

    matchLink := re.FindAllStringSubmatch(string(*data), -1)
```

If you wanted to make a bit more concurrent you could use channels and goroutines.

The expression `c.fetch(url)` could be a executed in a goroutine. You would have it fetch the URLs from the page and put those on a channel. In the main calling process you could have it pick up those URLs and fetch those and so forth.

```
go c.fetch(url)
```

If you want to have a look at mine, go [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/185795/multi-site-concurrent-web-crawler-using-grpc).

Answer (score 0):

I also wrote a crawler in go and have the following regex for sublinks only within the same domain.

```
    re := regexp.MustCompile("href=\"(.*?)\"")
    subre := regexp.MustCompile("\"/[\\w]+")

    matchLink := re.FindAllStringSubmatch(string(*data), -1)
```

If you want to have a look at mine [Multi Site Concurrent web crawler using gRPC](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/185795/multi-site-concurrent-web-crawler-using-grpc)