# Multi Site Concurrent web crawler using gRPC

Tags: beginner, web-scraping, go

This is the server portion of a gRPC implementation of a multi site concurrent web crawler.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "net"
    "net/http"
    "net/url"
    "regexp"
    "strings"
    "sync"
    "time"

    "golang.org/x/net/context"
    "google.golang.org/grpc"
)

// server is used to implement the crawler.CrawlerServer.
type server struct {
    spiderPtr *crawlerDS
}

// Crawler Interface...
type Crawler interface {
    pushURLToWaitingList(string, int, *chan int)
    parseLinks(*string, string, int, *chan int)
    crawler(string, int, *chan int)

    parseURL(string) (bool, string)
    listURLS() []string
    startCrawling()
    initHTTPRequestCapacity()
}

type linkIndex struct {
    index int
    url   string
}

const (
    port               = ":40052"
    concurrentRequests = 50
)

type crawlerDS struct {
    // Complete list of URLS visited and if they were put on channel to be visited.
    visitedUrls, urlOnChannel map[string]bool

    // URLS that were crawled
    finishedUrls chan string
    // Urls currently waiting to be crawled
    waitingUrls chan linkIndex

    // URL to Index Mapper
    siteURLIndex map[string]*linkIndex

    // Index to URL Mapper
    siteIndexURL map[int]string
    // Crawler Specific channel terminator
    terminate []*chan int
    // Number of sites being crawled
    siteIndex int
}

var (
    wg                          sync.WaitGroup
    mapLock                     = sync.RWMutex{}
    newsites                    = make(chan string, 1)
    shutdownSpecificSiteCrawler = make(chan linkIndex, 1)
    httpLimitChannel            = make(chan int, concurrentRequests)
)

func (c *crawlerDS) initHTTPRequestCapacity() {
    for i := 0; i < concurrentRequests; i++ {
        httpLimitChannel <- 1
    }
    return
}

// Method to find if uri has scheme and extract the hostname
func (c *crawlerDS) parseURL(uri string) (bool, string) {
    pg, err := url.Parse(uri)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    if pg.Scheme == "https" || pg.Scheme == "http" {
        return true, pg.Host
    }
    return false, ""

}

// pushes the new urls to the waiting urls channel to be processed
func (c *crawlerDS) pushURLToWaitingList(url string, index int, shutdown *chan int) {

    select {
    case _ = <-*shutdown:
        fmt.Println("Shutting down", url, index)
        return
    default:
        /*
            This needs more work to not place already visited
            urls back on the waitingList

            Getting race issues here
            if url has not been visited and the url has
            not yet been put on waiting channel
        */
        // mapLock.Lock()

        // if !c.visitedUrls[url] && !c.urlOnChannel[url] {
        //  c.urlOnChannel[url] = true
        c.waitingUrls <- linkIndex{index: index, url: url}
        // }
        // mapLock.Unlock()
    }
}

// Method that processes the href's in the crawled page
func (c *crawlerDS) parseLinks(data *string, pageURL string, index int, shutdown *chan int) {

    defer wg.Done()
    u, err := url.Parse(pageURL)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    re := regexp.MustCompile("href=\"(.*?)\"")
    subre := regexp.MustCompile("\"/[\\w]+")

    matchLink := re.FindAllStringSubmatch(string(*data), -1)
    for _, lk := range matchLink {

        if subre.MatchString(lk[0]) && lk[1] != pageURL {
            url := pageURL + lk[1]
            scheme, _ := c.parseURL(url)

            if scheme {
                c.pushURLToWaitingList(url, index, shutdown)
            }

        } else if strings.Contains(lk[1], u.Hostname()) {
            scheme, host := c.parseURL(lk[1])
            init, _ := url.Parse(pageURL)

            if scheme && host != init.Host {
                c.pushURLToWaitingList(lk[1], index, shutdown)
            }
        }
    }
}

// Method to crawl
func (c *crawlerDS) crawler(url string, index int, shutdown *chan int) {

    defer wg.Done()
    // This will limit the number of HTTP requests.
    <-httpLimitChannel
    resp, err := http.Get(url)
    httpLimitChannel <- 1

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    } else {
        select {
        case _ = <-*shutdown:
            // fmt.Println("Shutting down Crawler", url, index)
            return
        default:
            // push the crawled url onto the finishedURL channel
            c.finishedUrls <- url
            defer resp.Body.Close()
            body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
            if err != nil {
                log.Fatal(err)
            }
            msg := string(body)
            wg.Add(1)
            go c.parseLinks(&msg, url, index, shutdown)
        }

    }
}

// Method to print the site tree.
func (c *crawlerDS) listURLS() []string {
    mapLock.RLock()
    defer mapLock.RUnlock()
    links := make([]string, 0)
    for k := range c.visitedUrls {
        links = append(links, k)
    }

    return links
}

func (c *crawlerDS) startCrawling() {
    defer wg.Done()
    wg.Add(1)
    // Initialize the request throttler channel
    go c.initHTTPRequestCapacity()

    for {
        select {

        case finURL, ok := <-c.finishedUrls:
            if ok {
                fmt.Println("Crawled URL", finURL)
                mapLock.Lock()
                c.visitedUrls[finURL] = true
                mapLock.Unlock()
            }
        case obj := <-c.waitingUrls:
            wg.Add(1)
            go c.crawler(obj.url, obj.index, c.terminate[obj.index])

        case url := <-newsites:
            fmt.Println("Received new site to crawl", len(newsites), url, c.siteIndex)

            // Every site should have a shutdown channel
            shutdown := make(chan int, 1)
            mapLock.Lock()
            c.terminate = append(c.terminate, &shutdown)

            c.siteURLIndex[url] = &linkIndex{index: c.siteIndex, url: url}
            c.siteIndexURL[c.siteIndex] = url
            mapLock.Unlock()

            wg.Add(1)
            go c.crawler(c.siteIndexURL[c.siteIndex], c.siteIndex, &shutdown)
            c.siteIndex++

        case obj := <-shutdownSpecificSiteCrawler:
            mapLock.RLock()
            close(*c.terminate[obj.index])
            delete(c.siteURLIndex, obj.url)
            delete(c.siteIndexURL, obj.index)
            mapLock.RUnlock()

        default:
            time.Sleep(5 * time.Second)
            continue
        }

    }
    wg.Wait()

}

// Crawl method implementation for the gRPC
func (s *server) Crawl(ctx context.Context, in *pb.LinkRequest) (*pb.CrawlerResponse, error) {
    mapLock.RLock()
    // given a URL checks to see if its currently being crawled
    _, exists := s.spiderPtr.siteURLIndex[in.Url]
    mapLock.RUnlock()
    if exists {
        msg := fmt.Sprintf("Site %s is already being crawled", in.Url)
        return &pb.CrawlerResponse{Message: msg}, nil
    }
    // put new site on channel
    newsites <- in.Url
    return &pb.CrawlerResponse{Message: "Crawler started crawling"}, nil
}

// Stop method implementation for the gRPC
func (s *server) Stop(ctx context.Context, in *pb.StopRequest) (*pb.StopResponse, error) {
    mapLock.RLock()
    // given a URL checks to see if its currently not being crawled
    indx, exists := s.spiderPtr.siteURLIndex[in.Link]
    mapLock.RUnlock()
    if !exists {
        msg := fmt.Sprintf("Site %s is not being crawled", in.Link)
        return &pb.StopResponse{Message: msg}, nil
    }
    shutdownSpecificSiteCrawler <- linkIndex{url: in.Link, index: indx.index}

    return &pb.StopResponse{Message: "Crawler Stopping"}, nil
}

// List Visited URLS implementation for the gRPC
func (s *server) ListVisitedUrls(in *pb.ListRequest, stream pb.Crawler_ListVisitedUrlsServer) error {

    for _, link := range s.spiderPtr.listURLS() {
        ln := &pb.LinkRequest{Url: link}
        if err := stream.Send(ln); err != nil {
            return err
        }
    }
    return nil
}

// gRPC main server process
func main() {
    lis, err := net.Listen("tcp", port)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Failed to start gRPC server: %v", err)
    }

    // Creates a new gRPC server
    srvr := grpc.NewServer()
    ds := crawlerDS{visitedUrls: make(map[string]bool),
        urlOnChannel: make(map[string]bool), siteURLIndex: make(map[string]*linkIndex),
        siteIndex: 0, finishedUrls: make(chan string), siteIndexURL: make(map[int]string),
        waitingUrls: make(chan linkIndex), terminate: make([]*chan int, 0)}

    wg.Add(1)
    go ds.startCrawling()

    pb.RegisterCrawlerServer(srvr, &server{spiderPtr: &ds})
    srvr.Serve(lis)
}
```

I would appreciate if you could comment on my code and provide ways I can improve it.